# DataTable Filtration Method of "DATATABLE"

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I want to make a *method* that takes a `DataTable` as argument and *returns* a `DataTable` after performing a specific operation.

That opertion is to get those *rows* from passed `DataTable` which has `NULL` value in **Camp** column.

```
public DataTable Filter(DataTable table)
{
    return table;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataView` can be use to make *filter* from your data as:

```
public DataTable Filter(DataTable table)
{
    DataView view = new DataView(table);
    view.RowFilter = "Camp IS NULL"; 
    table = view.ToTable();
    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataView` to get filtered result from your `DataTable`.

```
public DataTable Filter(DataTable table)
{
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Sample code you presented doesn't include usage of `DataView` or any logic you meant to suggest

Answer (score 0):

```
public DataTable Filter(DataTable table)
{
    return table.Select("Camp is null").CopyToDataTable();
}
```